# How do I add ending tags (html)

Tags: sed, html

I need to add `</span>` before every following `<span.*` aka. the "endig tag" for all rows in the "page".

example row:

```
<span class="bold">│<span class="f9"> 1,245,732 <span class="f0"><span class="bold">│<span class="f9"> —             <span class="f0">
```

Fiddled with sed, but just can't get it working...

Please help for I know this is trivial for some/most of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given line on the format that you show, the following would add `</span>` before each `<span` , and then remove the one that was added at the very start and add one at the very end.

```
sed -e 's,<span ,</span>&,g' -e 's,^</span>,,' -e 's,$,</span>,'
```

I'm using commas as delimiters in the `s` commands as the strings that we use contains `/`.

Comment: THANKS! , I ended up with:
sed -e 's,<span ,</span>&,g' -e 's,^</span>,,' -e 's,\(<span.*\)$,\1</span>,'
for Your command adds </span> at the end of EVERY line and I have other kind of lines as well.

Comment: `sed -e 's,<span ,</span>&,g' -e 's,^</span>,,' -e 's,\(<span.*\)$,\1</span>,' `

of course.. :)